# Custom HTTP 403 page not working in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to replace the default access denied page:

[image: HTTP 403]

With my custom page and my approach was this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContextConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/security/checkpoint/for/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/rest/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome").permitAll().and().logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout");
}

@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    return daoAuthenticationProvider;

}

@Bean
public ProviderManager providerManager() {

    List<AuthenticationProvider> arg0 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
    arg0.add(daoAuthenticationProvider());

    return  new ProviderManager(arg0);

}

@Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManagerBean")
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return providerManager();
}

    @Bean
    public ExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter() {
        ExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter = 
                new ExceptionTranslationFilter(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        exceptionTranslationFilter.setAccessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

        return exceptionTranslationFilter;
    }
    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler() {
        AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandlerImpl = new 
                AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
        accessDeniedHandlerImpl.setErrorPage("/page_403.jsp");
        System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED IS CALLED......");
        return accessDeniedHandlerImpl;
    }

    private class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException,
                ServletException {

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,
                    "Access denied.");
        }

    }   

}
```

But with this config above I'm still not getting the job done and seeing the same

[image: HTTP 403]

Are there more bean which must be injected for this purpose?

Comment: Which even more clearly shows you haven't configured anything but a couple of beans. Just adding beans isn't going to help, also you are making it way to complex it can be done easier (see the answers and the reference guide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer** : this is not only solution, but a working one.

In this case my approach would be as simple as possible which is add this method in your SecurityContext

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/security/checkpoint/for/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/rest/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome").permitAll().and().logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/page_403");//this is what you have to do here to get job done.
}
```

Reference: [Custom 403 Page in Spring Security](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/).

Answer (score 1):

As @M. Deinum pointed out, you should tell Spring Security how to incorporate these beans. Anyway, there is a much simpler way for what you're trying to achieve:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContextConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Rest omitted

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // The usual stuff
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/page_403.jsp")
                    .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                    });
    }
}
```